# Selecting text by triple click or 'overselecting' results in new Lines upon pasting

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

- Using React/Ts, I have a method that display a user input:

```
function displayMsg({ msg}: UsrMsg) {

    return (
       <div>
          {msg.split('\n').map((line) => (
             <Fragment>{line}</Fragment>
          ))}
       </div>
    );
}
```

The problem is that when triple clicking then copying and pasting I get an extra line in the pasted text as such:

#### input One-liner:

```
blabla msg
```

#### output Two-liner:

```
blabla msg
```

#### Input: Multi-Line

```
bla1
bla2
bla3
```

#### Output: Multi-Line.

This happens ONLY after selecting with *3 CLICKS*, copying, then pasting.
With normal 2-clicks-selecting, this problem is not present :/

```
bla1
bla2
bla3
```

I tried playing around with the CSS by using the whiteSpace prop, but it didn't make a difference. :(

The issue is consistent on Firefox, chrome and edge.

#### Edit 1:

The used OS is windows. I haven't tested it on other OS.

#### Edit 2:

I suspect that the HTML tag is being copied along with the 3-clicks-selection OR "Over-selecting", thus when pasted being displayed as a line break.

Same issue can be seen a lot among the internet. Per example, take Worldcounter.net
Here is an image that shows you the result from the world counter!

[Try to copy the selected text as shown in the image, then paste it :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyeut.png)

Comment: Are you use it's not the OS' copying that causes it?

Comment: The used OS is windows. I haven't tested it on other OS. i just added this to the post

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> The problem is that when triple clicking then copying and pasting I get an extra line in the pasted text

**Cause :**

> I tried triple clicking on any pages on browser, then copy pasted that text in Notepad++. After that I enabled a setting  by going into `View Tab` > `Show Symbol` > `Show All Characters`.
> I found that on some pages, triple clicked copied text(from some tags like p tag, li tag had) contains `CRLF` control characters. `CRLF` control character tells next character to go on the next line and then to the beginning of the line.

**Solution :**

- Try changing that pattern `\n` to `\r\n` which will target `CRLF` character.
- Further you may also filter the result, to remove empty characters. By using `trim()` on msg, then `split` & using `filter` return elements which are true(not null, undefined, "") & then `map`.

  ```
  <div>
    {msg.trim().split('\r\n').filter(e => e).map((line) => (
        <Fragment>{line}</Fragment>
     ))}
  </div>
  ```

**Please Read :**

- CRLF : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CRLF

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment***